# virtual member call in constructor c#

Tags: c#, constructor, warnings, virtual-functions

In the constructor of my abstract `ClassA`, I am calling a virtual method and I am getting a warning from the compiler. I have included the links to the relevant documentation from Microsoft and NDepend. Here is my code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/Q_Constructor_should_not_call_a_virtual_method.html

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    private int m_number;
    protected ClassA()
    {
         m_number = GetNumber()
    }

    protected abstract int GetNumber(); 
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override int GetNumber()
    {
        return 10;
    }    
}
```

If I change my code in `ClassA` to call the virtual method indirectly through another method, I don't get any warnings. I'm not sure if this new design is better or what advantages it may have over the previous one. Here is the new code:

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    private int m_number;
    protected ClassA()
    {
         m_number = GetNumberIndirectly()
    }

    private int GetNumberIndirectly()
    {
        return GetNumber();
    }

    protected abstract int GetNumber(); 
}
```

I would like to know if the new design is better and what advantages it may have over the previous one.

Comment: Please include any warnings or other messages in your question. You can link that text to more information if wanted.

Comment: The first link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx) explains it pretty well. You should not call a virtual or abstract method from the constructor of a class. You could not be sure, that the object is initialized completely at this moment.

Comment: It is a Resharper and NDepend warnings. I have already included the links.

Comment: Your second version isn't better, it only avoids the warning.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen I know that. My question here is that why the second design works without warnings? Aren't they basically the same thing?

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen You answered it with the second comment.

Comment: Warnings usually mean something. It’s not a good idea to write contorted, obscure code just to avoid hearing the compiler telling you that you’re doing something sketchy.  Think about this: If the base class constructor hasn’t finished, clearly the subclass constructor hasn’t even started. Is the subclass override of the virtual method touching anything in the subclass that needs to be initialized? Well, it hasn’t been initialized yet.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks Ed. I know that. I was confused that why the second design passed the warnings!

Comment: About the second design in more detail. Tools like Reshaper do a very good job, but could not find all design problems. In this case: The tool generates a warning when it finds a call to a virtual method in the constructor code of a base class, but it did not check that the method, called by the constructor calls a virtual method.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen Thank you. I am still trying to find a good pattern to initialize the derived objects.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question which describes what you want to do and why you "need" to call the virtual method from the constuctor.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen My base class is abstract and there are fields in base class that need to be set from the derived class. I am afraid it is a bit too general to ask and may get red arrows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an alternative way:

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
    private int m_number;
    protected ClassA(int n)
    {
         m_number = n;
    }

    //protected abstract int GetNumber(); 
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public ClassB() : base(10)
    {
    }

    //protected override int GetNumber()
    //{
    //    return 10;
    //}    
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you, please mark it as useful.